# Spring transactional does not respect the order of execution

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, boot

I have been trying to understand/solve why custom queries executed at the end of the transaction block.

```
 @Transactional
    public void removeOrderFromPackages(OrderEntity entity, User currentUser) {
        List<PackageEntity> packages = packageRepository.findByOrderId(entity.getId()).stream().filter(f -> f.getStatus() != PackageStatus.COMPLETED).toList();
        for (PackageEntity aPackage : packages) {
            aPackage.setOrderItems(orderItemRepository.findByPackageId(aPackage.getId()));
            List<OrderItemEntity> entitiesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
            for (OrderItemEntity orderItem : aPackage.getOrderItems()) {
                if (orderItem.getOrder().getId().equals(entity.getId())) {
                    orderItem.setOrderPackage(null);
                    entitiesToRemove.add(orderItem);
                }
            }
            packageRepository.deleteOrderItemFromPackage(aPackage.getId(), entitiesToRemove.stream().map(OrderItemEntity::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
     // a few methods than executing
     packageRepository.saveAll(packages);
 }
```

The issue I am facing

```
@Query("Update OrderItemEntity oi set oi.orderPackage = null where oi.orderPackage.id = :packageId AND oi.id in (:orderItemIds)")
@Modifying
@Transactional
void deleteOrderItemFromPackage(Long packageId, List<Long> orderItemIds);
```

is the code block above executed after the `saveAll` method. I do not know why it happens. The way to solve this is to remove the custom queries. Why transactional does not execute the queries in order?

Comment: Please also include the actual executed sql from the log

Comment: That has nothing to do with transactional. Hibernate will try to determine an order on how to execute the statements. It will do this on flush, flush is performed before the commit (which is eventually triggered by the `@Transactional` processing at the end of the method).